# Whether twin primes satisfy this one?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

It seems that difference of squares of any twin primes $+1$ will always lead to
number which might be 

a) A square of a twin prime

b) Itself a twin prime

$C$ = ($A^2$-$B^2$ )+$1$ ------> $(1)$

Where 

$C$ --- > might be a twin prime or square of a twin prime,

$A$ and $B$ are twin primes where $A$ is > $B$

My questions is whether eqn ($1$) is true?

Comment: When you say $A$ and $B$ are twin primes with $A > B$, do you mean $A = B + 2$, or that $A$ can be *any* twin prime greater than $B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$, $B$ are twin primes, they differ by 2, so the conjecture seems to be that

> if $C = 2(A + B) + 1$, with $A$, $B$ twin primes, then $C$ is either a twin prime or square of a twin prime.

That's quickly falsified by taking $A = 101, B = 103$. For then $C = 409$ which is neither a twin prime nor the square of one.

Comment: Similarly 137, 139, 553 and many (most?) larger examples

Answer (score 2):

$\,(103^2-101^2)+1=409\,$ , which is neither of (a)-(b), though it is a prime.

$\,(4801^2-4799^2)+1=19201=7\cdot 13\cdot 211\,$ , which is neither of (a)-(b) and not even a prime

Comment: Again the number 19201 is a product of primes?

Comment: Well, *any* natural number is a prime or a product of primes except $\,1\,$....is this what you actually meant to ask?

Comment: I agree..need to work more on this..

Answer (score 1):

Some counterexamples:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
p & (p+2)^2-p^2+1 \\\hline
 137 & 7^1 \times 79^1 \\
 179 & 7^1 \times 103^1 \\
 197 & 13 \times 61^1 \\
 227 & 11^1\times  83^1 \\
 269 & 23^1\times  47^1 \\
 347 & 7^1\times  199^1 \\
 431 & 7^1\times  13^1\times  19^1
\end{array}
$$